# To merge the value key:value RDD having common key

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am new to spark using python so forgive if the question sounds basic. If I have a RDD:

```
[(((1, 0), 0.0), (2, 0)),
 (((1, 0), 0.0), (3, 0)),
 (((2, 0), -0.0), (1, 0)),
 (((2, 0), -0.0), (3, 0)),
 (((3, 0), -0.0), (1, 0)),
 (((3, 0), -0.0), (2, 0))]
```

I want to merge the values having the common key. So basically my output should be-

```
[(((1, 0), 0.0), [(2, 0),(3,0)])
 (((2, 0), -0.0), [(1, 0),(3,0)])
 (((3, 0), -0.0), [(1, 0),(2,0)])]
```

I tried using `groupByKey()` but still unable to fetch the solution. Any help would be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:
`rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(list).collect()`

Comment: Can you [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)  the answer as well?